# Multidimensional Analysis - Calculate the volume of a region

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

I have the following set:

$$M=\left\{ (x,y,z) \ | \ 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq x, 0 \leq z\leq xy \right\}$$

I am completely new to multidimensional analysis, so how do I even start when there is no $f(x,y)$ given here? 
Here is my attempt:

$$\int_0^{xy} \int_0^x \int_0^1 1 \ dx \ dy \ dz$$

Comment: It was a while ago I did this. In general what I think you need is a functional determinant. But if you have a constant ON coordinate system for $(x,y,z)$ it should become 1 to integrate any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make that
$$\int_0^1\int_0^x\int_0^{xy} 1\,dz\,dy\,dx.$$

Comment: Does the order of the integration matter (Fubini's theorem)? If it does, why do I have to integrated with respect to "z" first?
PS Thank you for replying!

Comment: It's a question of whether your limits make sense in the first place. Doing the integral you wrote down would give a function of $x$ and $y$, when you are just seeking a number... @Infecto

Comment: With your help, and the help of the user "mathreadler" I have got the solutoion 1/8. The only thing that remains is for me to sketch this volume. Any tips on how to do that? Do I need to draw a cartesic coordinate system and then find a few points which satisfy the (in)equations given in M?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on my functional determinant comment. If x is measured in decimeters, y in centimeters and z in meters your functional matrix would be

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0.1&0&0\\0&0.01&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and the determinant would in this simple example be diagonal product $0.1\cdot 0.01 \cdot 1 = 0.001$. So the functional determinant keeps track of how the volume is "rescaled" at each point in your set. In our case each volume element would be 1 thousandth time as big as if we measured each dimension in meters.

---

If all dimensions are unit $1$ lengths, we would get the functional determinant of the identity matrix, which is where you get your $1$ in your integral from.

Comment: Understood! Nice explanation! Thank you!

Comment: An upvote is a nice way to say thank you on the site.